# Postman returns "Error: passed a null parameter" when using Client Certificate

Tags: postman, client-certificates, mtls

I requested certificate from my CA (on a MAC) then exported the private key as p12 file.
In Postman preferences I configured Client Certificates by PFX file/passphrase:
[image]

I know it's reading it since I get incorrect passphrase error if set a wrong one.

Once it's set, I get error shown below in Postman Console: "Error: passed a null parameter" and the request is not being sent to server -- any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work after exporting from KeyChain both the "private key" and "certificate" together to a p12 file.

Comment: Can you elaborate the steps what you have done so that you were able to solve it in postman ?

Comment: Thank you Ben! had the same problem from curl but this fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it worked for me. @Kiran you need to export the certificate with a private key like below:

X509Certificate2 certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(certificatePem,privateKeyPEM);
certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, password);